# What the phrase "for social reform" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

***Martin Luther King, Jr., fought **for social reform.***

Here,I think the adverbial phrase means:-

For the Improvement of society as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Social policy](https://www.lse.ac.uk/social-policy/about-us/What-is-social-policy) is concerned with the ways societies across the world meet human needs for security, education, work, health and wellbeing. Social policy addresses how states and societies respond to global challenges of social, demographic and economic change, and of poverty, migration and globalisation.

*Social reform* is a change of social policy, targeting at an improvement of welfare.

Answer (score 1):

The core meaning of **reform** refers to "change(s) in structure", and in this case the "structure" is both the system of justice and  entrenched attitudes relating to race.

**for** means "promoting, seeking"

"seeking changes in law and attitude" (relating specifically to racial justice)